# How can I make an if using parsec (Haskell) to verify the input generated by an optional choice?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have this algebraic datatype:

```hs
data Arithmetic = Sum Int Int | Mult Int Int
    deriving (Show)
```

And I want to do this:

```hs
parseArith :: Parser Arithmetic
parseArith = do
    a <- many1 digit
    spaces
    string "+" <|> string "*"
    spaces
    b <- many1 digit
    ...
```

Where on the "...", I would verify whether it has a "+" or a "*", can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a slight alternative to Franky's answer, make your choice return the constructor you need later on.

```
parseArith :: Parser Arithmetic
parseArith = do
    a <- many1 digit
    spaces
    op <- (string "+" >> return Sum)
      <|> (string "*" >> return Mult)
    spaces
    b <- many1 digit
    spaces
    return $ op (read a) (read b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
...
op <- string "+" <|> string "*"
spaces
b <- many1 digit
... check op here
```

The doc of https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v:string is the same usecase you have.